# Weighted moving average with partitions in SQL

Tags: sql, moving-average, weighted

I have a simple table with sales of different products by date (YYYYMMDD). There are many days and many products. The table looks like this:

```
date      product     sales
...
20210101  Apples       112
20210101  Bananas      13
20210102  Apples       12
20210102  Bananas      101
20210103  Apples       18
20210103  Bananas      155
20210101  Lemons       14
...
```

I need to calculate a 3-day weighted moving average for each of the products. The main tricky thing is with partition. I am trying to squeeze it in this code:

```
    SELECT table.date,
       max(table.sales) as sales,
       CASE 
       WHEN table.date - (select min(date) from table) >1
       THEN sum(weighting * ma_table.sales)
       END as WMA 
FROM table
JOIN table AS ma_table ON table.date - ma_table.date BETWEEN 0 AND 2
JOIN (SELECT id_1, 1/(2 + 1.) as weighting FROM (VALUES (0, 1, 2)) as t(id_1)) weights ON
  id_1 = table.date - ma_table.date
GROUP BY table.date
ORDER BY table.date
```

Is there anything that can be done with this code to include partition there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is SQL to calculate 3-days moving average for each product,
using window function.
Is this what you want?

```
with
a as ( -- serial numbers upto N (=3)
    select row_number() over () as i
    from TBL
    limit 3
),
b as (
  select
      TBL.date, TBL.product, TBL.sales,
      lag("sales", cast(a.i - 1 as integer)) 
        over(partition by TBL.product, a.i order by date) as sales2,
      (3 - a.i + 1) as weight
  from TBL
  cross join a
)
select date, product, sales,
    sum(weight*sales2) / (3*(3+1)/2) as avg
from b
group by date, product, sales
order by product, date
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/434YbRiaadKXmiMM5zRwSA/0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not exactly. I am talking about a weighted moving average, not a simple one. 

When calculating the weighted moving average, the recent data points are assigned a greater weighting, whereas past data points are assigned less weighting. The sum of the weight should be equal to 1 or 100%.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me weighted moving average. I edit my SQL to calculate weighted 3-days moving average. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working great! It was my mistake - I used a simple moving average in my code, so it was confusing for you. My apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess it's like this then

> ```
> create table yourtable (
>  id int primary key, 
>  "date" date, 
>  product varchar(30), 
>  sales decimal(18,2)
> )
>
> insert into yourtable 
> (id, "date" , product, sales) values
>   (1, '2021-01-01', 'Apples',  112)
> , (2, '2021-01-02', 'Apples',   12)
> , (3, '2021-01-03', 'Apples',   18)
> , (4, '2021-01-01', 'Bananas',  13)
> , (5, '2021-01-02', 'Bananas', 101)
> , (6, '2021-01-03', 'Bananas', 155)
> , (7, '2021-01-01', 'Lemons',   14)
> ```

> ```
> select "date", product, sales
> , cast((prev2+prev1*2+sales*3)/(1+2+3) as decimal(18,2)) as WMA
> from (
> select "date", product, sales
> , lag(sales, 2, 0) over (partition by product order by "date") as prev2
> , lag(sales, 1, 0) over (partition by product order by "date") as prev1
> from yourtable
> ) q
> order by product, "date"
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | product |  sales |    wma
> :--------- | :------ | -----: | -----:
> 2021-01-01 | Apples  | 112.00 |  56.00
> 2021-01-02 | Apples  |  12.00 |  43.33
> 2021-01-03 | Apples  |  18.00 |  31.67
> 2021-01-01 | Bananas |  13.00 |   6.50
> 2021-01-02 | Bananas | 101.00 |  54.83
> 2021-01-03 | Bananas | 155.00 | 113.33
> 2021-01-01 | Lemons  |  14.00 |   7.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=343f3a845038a816000b5538d9d7395d)*

The numbers for an unbounded weighted rolling average might look like this.

> ```
> select "date", product, sales
> , cast(sum(cnt * sales) 
>        over (partition by product ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND current row)
>      / sum(cnt) 
>        over (partition by product ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND current row
>   ) as decimal(18,2)) as UnboundedWeightedMovingAverage
> from (
> select "date", product, sales
> , count(*) over (partition by product order by "date" asc) as cnt
> from yourtable
> ) q
> order by product, "date"
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | product |  sales | unboundedweightedmovingaverage
> :--------- | :------ | -----: | -----------------------------:
> 2021-01-01 | Apples  | 112.00 |                         112.00
> 2021-01-02 | Apples  |  12.00 |                          45.33
> 2021-01-03 | Apples  |  18.00 |                          31.67
> 2021-01-01 | Bananas |  13.00 |                          13.00
> 2021-01-02 | Bananas | 101.00 |                          71.67
> 2021-01-03 | Bananas | 155.00 |                         113.33
> 2021-01-01 | Lemons  |  14.00 |                          14.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dd43bac431e5888e44830b39561062b0)*